# Is a rental confirmation for a holiday home a valid proof of accommodation when applying for a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, tourist-visas, portugal, proof-of-accommodation

To obtain as Ukrainian Citizen a Schengen Tourist Visa for visiting Portugal, do I need to book my holiday home through a traveling agency or can I use any offer on holiday rentals from an Internet Platform (global or local) and ask the property owner to write a booking confirmation letter to the embassy?

Would that letter be accepted by the embassy, if the holiday home is registered as holiday home with the Portuguese Ministry of Tourism?

**edit:**

can this proof be scanned and sent by email or do you need to present the original at the embassy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof of accommodation for a Schengen visa application needs to be a [document stating that you have reserved an accommodation for the length of the stay and that the reservation is confirmed](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0ahUKEwirq-2z6rXSAhXHXBQKHdrSDGoQFghoMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gold.ac.uk%2Fmedia%2Fdocuments-by-section%2Fabout-us%2Fgovernance%2Fimmigration-%2FPortuguese-Schengen-visa-application-guidance.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGcc2TG45QMiWPBCaTZaajq37vmXQ):

> [image]

Whether you are staying in a hostel, a rented room or a 5* hotel does not matter. Since you want to rent a house, you can rent it directly from the owner. At that point you should sign a rental contract stating the duration of the stay, the cost of the rental, the conditions, etc. This contract, signed by all parties, is a valid proof of accommodation.

As an added tip, I would suggest you sign an extra copy of the contract specifically for the embassy, to be included in your visa application.

Comment: would they accept a rental conrtact signed and scanned and then sent by email?

Comment: @Vickel I would guess yes. The hotel reservation one usually sends are not "original" copies per se, they are printouts of confirmation emails. However, if you are going to the embassy for an interview, take a copy of the contract with you. Even better, sign an extra copy just for the embassy.

Comment: I've not accepted your answer (yet), because the document you attached in your answer is about getting a Schengen Visa for someone who holds currently a UK Visa. My specific case is about the documents needed for an Ukrainian citizen to get their tourist visa in the Portuguese consulate of Kiev.

Comment: @Vickel Yeah I've tried looking for official guidelines but these are hard to find. A proof of accommodation is technically not even required by the Schengen visa regulations. Proof of funds to support your stay should be enough. However many if not all consulates ask for proof of accommodation. IMHO the best way to go about it is to be honest and thorough when providing supporting documents. Draft a legal rental contract containing all the required information (the more the better) and have it signed by all parties. You should be fine then.

Comment: There has been a turnaround, now the embassy's employee wants notarized signatures, I don't feel the property owner will do that, just because of the time and money they'll need to spend... what now?

Comment: @Vickel Wow that's a harsh requirement. I'm not even sure it's legal. I'll ask Gayot. Anyway if you're in a rush I'm sure the house owner will get a notarised signature if you pay for it.

Comment: @Vickel I am afraid the immigration officer can ask for all the documentation they deem necessary. At this point I would advise you to get the notarised signature.